# Hide all inherited properties of usercontrol class at design time in VS2010 property browser

Tags: c#

I have create my own usercontrol which is inherited from usercontrol. Is there a solution to hide all inherited properties of usercontrol class at design time in VS2010 property browser,
so that i can see only my custom properties in the property window in the VS2010 IDE at design time?
I'm using WPF usercontrol. Is there something like the controldesigner for usercontrols in winforms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just the way [this link says](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/56028/Hiding-inherited-properties):

1. Create a property with the name of the property you don't want to be shown
2. Define a default getter and setter for it
3. Use `Browsable` and `EditorBrowsable` attributes to hide it

Comment: I'm using a WPF usercontrol. Is there something like the controldesigner for usercontrols in winforms or adding the browsable attribute via code to the inherited properties?